# SQLITE3 - How do I add values to a column using a variable as the column name?

Tags: python, json, database, sqlite

How do I use the variable "element" as the name for the column when inserting values? When I run it, it tries to add a value to a column named element however, I want it to insert the value into the column with the name which is assigned to "element".

```
import sqlite3
import json

with open('myDataFile.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)


for element in d["cards"][0]:
    con = sqlite3.connect("MTGcards.db")
    cur =  con.cursor()
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO Cards (element) VALUES (?)""",(d["cards"][0][element]))
    con.commit
    cur.close()
    con.close()
```

If it helps to know, "d" is a large json file with card stats for different cards from Magic the Gathering. I'm trying to insert each stat for a card into its corresponding column in a database, so it's name goes into the name column ect...

This is what I get back.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\NEA code\jsonFileReadTest.py", line 11, in <module>
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO Cards (element) VALUES (?)""",(d["cards"][0][element]))
sqlite3.OperationalError: table Cards has no column named element
```

Comment: Please note that INSERT adds an entire row to the table.

Comment: @CL What would I need to do so It only adds the value to a single column with the name assigned to element?

Comment: Read any SQL tutorial. Anyway, I suspect that it would be a better idea to store the elements in rows, not columns.